# Convert Data Type from SQL Reading in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

Hello I have sql Table with ***date*** and ***time*** and ***Decimal*** So everithing is ok when I select and see this column in sql and sql result but when i read this data in python something is change and I dont know why ! Like **Date** and **Time** that convert to `datetime` and `timedelta` or **Decimal** didnt Convert to float and be `Decimal('String')`  :/ !

I take screenshot from both **SQL** and **python** Result in Photo below:

[image]

The order is regular and each yellow box is equal to the orange box,Of course their numbers are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I find the Answer and I think maybe some one Get into this problem in reading data from mysql database in python.

time Variable type is datetime.deltatime and it is seconds so it have built-in method in str() to convert it to real datetime value Hour:Minutes:Second.

date Variable type is datetime.datetime and because it we can take year or day or.... from it.

I use this 2 method to convert Date and Time to what they really are :

```
import datetime

date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

time = str(time)
```

and the output is :

```
08/11/2020
1:17:41
```